# How to always prepend a common to certain specific commands

Tags: bash

I had three commands (composer, yarn, wp) that I would like to be always prepended with another command (lando) while still accepting parameters. So:

`composer install` --> `lando composer install`

`yarn build:production` --> `lando yarn build:production`

`wp option get home --https://somesite` --> `lando wp option get home --https://somesite`

and so on.

Aliased commands do not seem to accept parameters or flags.

I've found solutions for appending some commands, or for prepending all commands, but nothing for prepending only commands. Can this be done?

Comment: So you are not happy with `alias composer='lando composer'` because it would also turn `composer anything` in `lando composer anything` whereas you want it to happen only for `composer install`?

Comment: As far as I can tell `alias composer='lando composer'` cannot accept parameters. `composer` expands to `lando composer` but `composer anything` doesn't trigger the alias and runs regular `composer anything`